# HP Laserjet 1020 loses its configuration after every reboot

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.02 LTS and have a HP LaserJet 1020 printer.
I have set up that printer in Ubuntu with the command `sudo hp-setup -i`.

At first, everything was fine and I was able to print something. But now every time I restart my computer, I can't print anything. I have to set up that printer again.

Why am I losing my printer configuration/installation after every reboot?
How can I fix this and make it persistent?

Comment: Have you considered using the GUI method?

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with not retaining the firmware when it comes back from boot. I've saw some remedies, but they make my head hurt.

I've had your problem with many linux distros on multiple computers with the hp-1020 printer. I've tried a lot of things over time with no luck. Then I discovered purging the printer drivers in terminal with the lines below  (this is on linux mint 17.1, don't know if the drivers are same on Ubuntu. Do this method at your own risk.)

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove printer-driver-foo2zjs-common
sudo apt-get --purge remove printer-driver-foo2zjs
```

Then afterwards in terminal use `sudo hp-doctor` to put back everything purged (use the `a` option to `install all` when it gets to the point of asking).

If hp-doctor stops at some point because it can't see the printer. It will say cut printer on and run hp-doctor again. At that point cut printer on if off, or if it's already on like mine was, then cut it off then on again and re-run `hp-doctor`

If you're lucky, the doctor won't have any complaints the second time and printer will continue to work after every reboot. Mine did.